# How can I create limits of integration in Word 2007's equation editor?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, equation-editor

Specifically, how can I create the limits of integration for the antiderivative of an integral (see freehand circle)?

[image: Limits of integration]

Comment: Word 2007 has an equation editor which accepts a syntax not unlike Latex, and I need to do the thing in red :).  The best thing I've come up with is, in this example, `|^u_0` which is adding a superscript `u` and subscript `0` to a pipe (`|`), but it looks pretty abysmal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify an empty left bracket with `\left`. Your specific example would look like this:

```
\left 1/2 v^2+(u+1)v|_0^u
```

or after replacements:

```
├ 1/2 v^2+(u+1)v┤|_0^u
```

[image: Typeset formula]

Actually, it's pretty much the same technique you would use in (La)TeX.

Minor nitpick: You should use `\dd` for the integration d in the formula. This automatically ensures an upright glyph and a small space before the d.

Comment: Excellent response, thanks!  The example is actually a screenshot of a PDF of lecture notes, so it's not my fault I swear! `|^u_0`

Comment: You really like that smiley, don't you? :-)

Answer (score 5):

In the Equation's Design tab, click on Bracket and insert the Single Bracket that has a straight line to the left, and its contents go to the right. Click inside its content dotted box and the click on Bracket again but this time choose the Stack Object - the one without parameters. That should get you there. All you have to do now is fill in the bottom and upper boxes. I hope this helps.

Comment: There is a better way to do this. For the second step, instead of going to Bracket, go to Script and select the one with three empty boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Can't get anything that looks very good, but you can add a fraction, then right click that to remove the dividing line ('fraction bar'), this at least gives you the effect of a superscript directly above a subscript which looks OK.
Using character 2502 instead of pipe is a slightly better version of a longer vertical line, but still way off ideal.
You could split this into two equations in separate controls, then put the pipe between them, which gives you the option to change the font size independently from the rest.

Last resort, do everything else (including a fraction with no dividing line), then use the shapes tool to draw a vertical line where you need it (hold shift while you draw to snap to true vertical)

Comment: Ouch, that's painful :-)

Comment: It hurt me too. Glad someone came up with the proper syntax for this instead of doing it either of these ways!

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this is to type the following:

[\vphantom(a/b) f(x)]^b_a

\vphantom will create an invisible item with the height of the bit in parentheses but 0 width. Make sure to hit space after the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are needing the square brackets representing an integral evaluation???

If so create a regular square bracket with the integral within it then highlight the entire bracket and go to the "script" button and select the third option encompassing superscript and subscript.

Your square brackets will now have the limits of integration on them.